# What scripting language should be used to deploy Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes

I have to deploy a Kubernetes cluster, and I currently use `bash` to set up the security key, the environment prop, create pods etc with `kuberctl`. But I am wondering if `bash` is a good choice to used when the deployment steps getting big. E.g. ~50 deployment and services.

Is that a better choice than `bash` on deploying system under kubernetes? Any good example of automatic deployment under Kubernetes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to install/manage resources in kubernetes the advised solution is to use [Helm Package Manager](https://github.com/kubernetes/helm).

> Helm is a tool for managing Kubernetes charts. Charts are packages of
>   pre-configured Kubernetes resources.

So most configurations would belong to applications and tools charts.

Then you can use a third party tool (anSible, puppet, chef) in order to help with the automation. 
In general I prefer to use [Ansible](https://www.ansible.com) as it relies mainly on ssh commands and it's easier to manage compared to Chef and Puppet whose scripts get really messy real quick. 
I prefer composition over orchestration.

Comment: I find `Helm` and `Ansible` is the good way to start with. While what do you mean `prefer composition over orchestration`? I can't get the meaning of it.

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to check ksonnet/kubecfg. It is designed for declaratively managing Kubernetes deployments https://github.com/ksonnet/kubecfg

Taken from their website:

> The idea is to describe as much as possible about your configuration
>   as files in version control (eg: git).
>
> Changes to the configuration follow a regular review, approve, merge,
>   etc code change workflow (github pull-requests, phabricator diffs,
>   etc). At any point, the config in version control captures the entire
>   desired-state, so the system can be easily recreated in a QA cluster
>   or to recover from disaster.